# Laravel How can I remove unique column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, unique

This is mine

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('customer_plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropUnique('customer_plans_code_unique');
        $table->string('code',255)->change();
        $table->string('name',255)->change();
    });
}
```

I do this as laravel.com but i got this error

```
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP   'customer_plans_code_unique'; check that column/
  key exists
```

Anyone knows this error, please tell me!
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `$table->dropUnique('customer_plans_code_unique');` from your code.

Without seeing the rest of the code I can't tell if having that line is important or not, but it's definitely the reason you're seeing the error.

Show me your up() function and I can give you more feedback.

Comment: just only `$table->unique('code',50);` in up(). Thanks you!

Comment: In that case, only `$table->dropUnique('code');` should be in your `down()` function. Also, if you found my answer helpful, I'd appreciate if you'd accept it.